# L1 as Probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a continuous optimization problem, I consider the functions belonging to the "space of probabilities" on $\lbrack 0,1 \rbrack^N $ that admit a probability density. I understand that I exclude in the process distributions such as the Dirac.

Can I use a subset of the Lebesgue $L_1(\lbrack 0,1 \rbrack^N) $  space for that matter?
To be specific, can I use :
$$ \{ p \in L_1 | \int p = 1, p\geq0 \} $$

Comment: Yes,you can. This identification is useful in many ways.

Comment: This is not fully accurate. What is the underlying space of $L_1$? What measure are integrating the function $p$ against?

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers. $L_1$ is defined on $\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack^N$ where N is an integer, and the measure is the Lebesgue measure. I will edit the question.